# Radio Button Group -> what value should it be given to - .setSelected()

Tags: javascript, radio-button, sapui5

What kind of value should `.setSelectedButton` be given in order to select a specific Button within a `RadioButtonGroup` Construct.

What I tried:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("RadioButtonGroup").setSelectedButton("idOftheButton")
```

Expected Result: `It selects this specific Button`
Actual Result: `Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the parameter for `setSelectedButton` is the `sap.m.RadioButton` object itself, so depending on how you register and declare everything it's something closer to:

```
var button = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idOftheButton"); //find the button
sap.ui.getCore().byId("RadioButtonGroup").setSelectedButton(button);
```

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/api/sap.m.RadioButtonGroup/methods/setSelectedButton